# looping a function and changing only one argument variable with each iteration

Tags: r, function, loops, arguments

I am trying to figure out how to loop a function such that it changes one argument in a function to match the variable in a list

```
data=mtcars
carb=4
list<-list(1,2,4,5,6)

func<-function(data, cyln, carbn){
  a<-data%>%group_by(cyl==cyln,carb==carbn)%>%count
  print(a)
}

function(mtcars,list,4)...or something where cyl takes its value from the list.
```

where I am basically trying to get the function to show me the count (a) for each different cylinder as included in the list.

So, to print the individual counts for 1 cyl, 4 carb; 2 cyl, 4 carb; 4 cyl, 4 carb; 5 cyl, 4 carb; 6 cyl, 4 carb.

i couldnt think of a way to lapply the list to the function in such a way that i could just change the cylinder argument/variable

Any help appreciated

edit for clarity:

What I am trying to do is loop so that the function takes a new element from the list each iteration. Inside the function with each loop would be something like:

```
a<-data%>%group_by(cyl==1, carb)%>%count 
  print(a)
```

the second is

```
a<-data%>%group_by(cyl==2, carb)%>%count
  print(a)
```

the third is

```
a<-data%>%group_by(cyl==4,carb)%>%count
   print(a)
```

and the 1, 2, 4 (cyl) comes from the list, while the other variable (carb) remains static at 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sapply` to iterate through each element of a vector containing the values for `cyl`. For example:

```
sapply(c(1,2,4,5,6), function(x)
  nrow(subset(mtcars, cyl == x & carb == 4)))

[1] 0 0 0 0 4
```

I'm assuming you just used `mtcars` as example data, since the only values for `cyl` in that dataset are 4, 6, 8, and only `cyl = 6, carb = 4` returns values > 0.

Comment: That works here but it isn't using the created function to apply the numbers in the list. that was an example function because creating a reprex with the actual function im using would be too cumbersome. is there a way to set cyl == x in the function and have x = list, and iterate to print the output on a new line each iteration?

Comment: Your example function has quite a few errors. For example: you can't `group_by` on a list and you supply no arguments to `count`. Generally it helps others if your question is as close to the problem you're trying to solve as possible.

Comment: the list is where i would like the iteration of the element of the list such that the first is: `a<-data%>%group_by(cyl==1, carb)%>%count,  print(a)`, the second is `a<-data%>%group_by(cyl==2, carb)%>%count,  print(a)`, the third is `a<-data%>%group_by(cyl==4,carb)%>%count,  print(a)` and the 1, 2, 3 comes from the list, while the other variable (carb) remains static at 4. I will add to the original post so I can format

Comment: found a solution using map: map(list, ~ func(data = mtcars, cyln = ., carbn = 4))

Answer (score 0):

reddit user and-another-one gave me this solution and it works great! :

Rather than a loop, try map from the purrr library. You can insert dummy arguments into the function (.) to represent the value that is changing and set the data and carbn whatever you want. Just remember to use a tilda (~) before the function so it treats it as a formula.

```
map(list, ~ func(data = mtcars, cyln = ., carbn = 4))
```